# How can I multiply a string in this case?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a code. In this code I have a label1 with text: "0,5 min", from substring I get "0,5" and now I need to convert it from minutes to milliseconds like 0,5 * 60 * 1000 = 30000. I can't do it because of this error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

How can I do it?

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string num = label1.Text.Substring(0, label1.Text.IndexOf(" min"));
    int mul = Convert.ToInt32(num) * 60 * 1000;

    textBox1.Text = $"{num} - {mul}";
    await Task.Delay(mul);
}
```

Comment: You should either use a dot as decimal-seperator, or provide your locale-settings to [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-6.0#system-convert-toint32(system-string-system-iformatprovider))

Comment: Apart from this, `0.5` surely is not an integer, but a decimal, isn't it?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I don't know, that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: Why are you scraping that value off of a Label and not from a class field, which both informs the Label's Text _and_ the conversion?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain OP shouldn't use `Convert` _at all_.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I got my problem. I used integer not double!

Comment: @Fildor I entirely agree - Microsoft really needs to add `[Obsolete]` to the `Convert` class,  and it should have done so over a decade ago.

Comment: Reading this again, I think this is actually an x-y question. That value should not be taken from a label's Text property in the first place. It's a design smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the exact error you're getting, you might want to replace `,` with `.` (though ideally specify an explicit `CultureInfo`).

Then you can use `double.TryParse(num, out value);`

Also you might want to change it from `int` to `double` or `decimal` (use `decimal` if you need precision, [as `double` and `float` are inexact, approximate, types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)).

Comment: I won't dv, but I cannot stress this enough. The whole ordeal is unneccessary. OP should use a backing model, so that conversion is completely unneccessary. The label's Text property should then be bound to reflect that model's Value. Changes should be made to the model. And the delay in the question's click handler should use the model's value. For example a `TimeSpan` would be an excellent choice.

Comment: @Fildor WinForms' main strength is RAD though - going through the trouble of defining an internal domain model to mediate between the UI and whatever else is there would be considered _added and unnecessary complexity_ depending on the business requirements (i.e. get something-that-will-never-be-updated out the door asap) - not to mention the headaches people have with WinForm's anemic (if not broken) built-in databinding support - the kind of headaches that make people start-over with Electron because things are _just that bad_ now.

Comment: @Dai Agreed. And then you end up scraping values off of some label's text ... :/

Comment: @Fildor Did you agree to disagree? :) I cannot see how adding a simple Model binder that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` is *added and unnecessary complexity* as @Dai mentioned. That's standard / every-day implementation in this platform (as *in the other* platform). The *added complexity* is the (strings parsing + locale handling) shenanigans. That's what the OP should really avoid.

Comment: @Jimi I agreed to "WinForms' main strength is RAD". But yes, I kind of disagreed, too. He is kind of right in that binding is a little pain in the rear in WinForms. But the alternatives are mostly much worse as seen in the question. So, in the end it depends what you define as "added and unneccessary complexity".